# creating tuple within tuple within list from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a relatively small dataframe like:

```
    index  ColA  ColB  ColC
    0      A      B     C
    1      D      E     F
```

and so on.
I am trying to get a list of tuples back that looks like:

```
[((A,B),C), ((D,E),F)...]
```

Any assistance anyone can offer?

Comment: Hi all, benchmarking of even larger size of 1000000x size posted.  You can take a look.  The `iteritems`  approach is catching up with the `zip()` approach for larger size.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use `zip()` + list-comprehension:

```py
print([((a, b), c) for a, b, c in zip(df.ColA, df.ColB, df.ColC)])
```

Prints:

```py
[(('A', 'B'), 'C'), (('D', 'E'), 'F')]
```

Comment: Seems that this solution runs faster with both original size and 10000x larger size.  +1   (original size:  22.1 µs vs  299 µs ;  10000x size:  8.89 ms vs 20.8ms)

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertuples` and list comprehension:

```
[((t.ColA, t.ColB), t.ColC) for t in df.itertuples()]
# [(('A', 'B'), 'C'), (('D', 'E'), 'F')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Benchmarking result:

**1) Original size:**

```
%%timeit
[((t.ColA, t.ColB), t.ColC) for t in df.itertuples()]

299 µs ± 8.89 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
[((a, b), c) for a, b, c in zip(df.ColA, df.ColB, df.ColC)]

22.1 µs ± 612 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
[((t.ColA, t.ColB), t.ColC) for _, t in df.iterrows()]

145 µs ± 1.31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
[*df.set_index(['ColA','ColB'])['ColC'].iteritems()]

1.29 ms ± 28.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**2.  10000x larger size:**

```
df2 = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)
```

```
%%timeit
[((t.ColA, t.ColB), t.ColC) for t in df2.itertuples()]

19.5 ms ± 668 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
[((a, b), c) for a, b, c in zip(df2.ColA, df2.ColB, df2.ColC)]

8.39 ms ± 140 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
[((t.ColA, t.ColB), t.ColC) for _, t in df2.iterrows()]

1.32 s ± 26.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
%%timeit
[*df2.set_index(['ColA','ColB'])['ColC'].iteritems()]

10.4 ms ± 355 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**3.  1000000x larger size:**

```
df3 = pd.concat([df] * 1000000, ignore_index=True)
```

```
%%timeit
[((t.ColA, t.ColB), t.ColC) for t in df3.itertuples()]

2.05 s ± 51.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
%%timeit
[((a, b), c) for a, b, c in zip(df3.ColA, df3.ColB, df3.ColC)]

961 ms ± 9.73 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
%%timeit
[((t.ColA, t.ColB), t.ColC) for _, t in df3.iterrows()]

2min 4s ± 1.63 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
%%timeit
[*df3.set_index(['ColA','ColB'])['ColC'].iteritems()]

1.13 s ± 55.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: @SeaBean Seems the `.iteritems()` is comparable to `zip()` for large dataframes. The `.set_index()` consumes huge portion of time for small dfs.

Comment: @AndrejKesely  Yes, it seems so.  That's interesting I'm going to test for 1000000x, i.e. 100x times more than the large dataset. Stay tuned.

Comment: @AndrejKesely  Still the `zip()` approach fastest but the difference with `.iteritems()` is narrowing.

Answer (score 0):

Let us do `iteritems` after `set_index`

```
[*df.set_index(['ColA','ColB'])['ColC'].iteritems()]
Out[604]: [(('A', 'B'), 'C'), (('D', 'E'), 'F')]
```